# To average a subset of one column using pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, csv, python-3.6

I have a .csv file that I'm reading from. I read only select columns from it and I need to further process this data before I save it into an excel sheet. The idea is to repeat this process for all the files in the folder and save the sheets with the same names as the original .csv.

As of now, I'm able to read the specific columns from .csv and write the whole file into excel. I am yet to figure out how to further process these columns before I save to excel. Further processing involves

1. Averaging rows 18000-20000 for each column separately.
2. Calculating (Column value - Average)/Average
3. Saving these values in separate columns with different column names.

My code is as follows. Need some help with this.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path


for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f) #splitting into file name and extension

    if file_ext == '.atf':
        #open the data file and get data only from specific columns.
        df = pd.read_csv(f, header = 9, index_col = 0, usecols = [0,55,59,63,67,71,75,79,83,87,91,95,99,103], encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep = '\t', dtype = {'YFP.13':str,'YFP.14':str,'YFP.15':str,'YFP.16':str,'YFP.17':str,'YFP.18':str,'YFP.19':str,'YFP.20':str,'YFP.21':str,'YFP.22':str,'YFP.23':str,'YFP.24':str,'YFP.25':str,'Signals=':str}) 

        df.to_excel(file_name+'.xlsx',sheet_name=file_name, engine = 'xlsxwriter') #writing into an excel file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your dataframe has a shape of 4 columns and 100 rows:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

1. > Averaging rows 18000-20000 for each column separately.

To perform the averaging on a subset, you define a logical mask based on inequalities over the index and apply the averaging function on the selected dataframe. The results are saved in a new dataframe as you want to use them later:

```
means = data[(60<data.index) & (80>data.index)].mean()
```

2. > Calculating (Column value - Average)/Average
3. > Saving these values in separate columns with different column names

For the two last steps, the code below speaks by itself:

```
cols = data.columns
for col in cols:
    data[col +"_calc"] = (data[col]-means[col])/means[col]
```

In the end, you may export the dataframe "data" to an excel format as you did earlier.